# PyAutoGUI problem out of syntax (time.sleep)

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

This should be a program bot in the game in Python. made a couple of errors in the code find them I can not help

if it's not difficult to point out my error with a detailed answer, I will be very grateful

```
 import pyautogui
    import time
    m=0
    while m<=3600:
     m=m+1
    print("sesion")
    im = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0, 298, 1024))
    time.sleep(5)
    if locateOnScreen('1.png') == im:{
    pyautogui.press('esc')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('2.png')
    pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.25)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('up')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(360)
    pyautogui.press('end')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.typewrite('Dctv ghbdtn/ Rjve-nj yflj ghjrfxrf& Tckb lf/ Gbibnt d cjifk', interval=0.25)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(10)
    elif (pyautogui.locateOnScreen('4.png')):{ 
      pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    }
    else:
    pyautogui.press('end')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.typewrite('Dctv ghbdtn/ Rjve-nj yflj ghjrfxrf& Tckb lf/ Gbibnt d cjifk', interval=0.25)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(10)
    }
    pyautogui.press('esc')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('2.png')
    pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.25)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.locateOnScreen('3.png')
    pyautogui.click(clicks=2, interval=0.25)
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(360)
```

Comment: You have a couple of blocks of code that are surrounded by curly braces.  This isn't C, or any of the other languages where that makes any sense whatsoever: Python exclusively uses indention to indicate the extent of a block.

Comment: did not help C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\GTA\bot projekt>code.py
  File "C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\GTA\bot projekt\code.py", line 10
    pyautogui.press('esc')
            ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\GTA\bot projekt>pause
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Comment: C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\GTA\bot projekt>code.py
  File "C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\GTA\bot projekt\code.py", line 12
    time.sleep(0.5)
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\Дом\Desktop\GTA\bot projekt>pause
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .